# Cannot create patch from git commits Error creating patch: error: cannot read object

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a patch with git from specific commits but I'm receiving this error

`Error creating patch: error: cannot read object c482833595048231dd39a2bb0f97acdb7816eee6 '<dir/path>'`

I'm not sure what it is and how to fix it.

I've tried following instructions like `git fsck --full` and it appears clean. I can create commits fine.

I also tried a `git reset --hard` to no avail

This is a local git, there's no remote attached.

Any ideas how to fix?

I'm not interested at all in saving the data in the problematic dir/path

Comment: what command did you run to get the exact error?

Comment: I think it was a weird windows git issue. I did the same command via WSL and it created the patches correctly ` git format-patch 33731c32^..fcd64b4f`